Ctrl + fn + l shutdown system in arch + i3wm?
i'm using arch + i3wm.
When I press ctrl+fn+l, my system shuts down and I have to press the power button to restart it.
How do I know what process is involved with this combination and is it possible to change it or disable it?
Thanks in advance.

According to https://askubuntu.com/a/1236095/1912012, you should try editing /etc/systemd/logind.conf and set/add HandleSuspendKey=ignore.
However to me this seems more as an keyboard issue, as I've seen a pattern of people having a similar issue with one specific keyboard (Logitech K380)

my logitech is 580)))

thankyou, did like you wrote, and now ctrl+fn+l - nothing.
